# Java: array of sorted indexes

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, indexing

Quick question: I have an array `double[]array=new double [10]` in which there are random doubles, say between 0 and 20.
What i want is get another array `int []resultingArray=new int [array.length]` that each value int is the index of a value double of the `array[]` sorted form the biggest number to the smallest.
Since my english sucks here is a "diagram":

array = (2, 6, 3) ***_*__*_*_** resultingArray = (1, 2, 0)

It's an exam question. The doubles are GPAs from students and it asks for a method that returns an array composed of the IDs (which in my code are the indexes of double[]array) of the students from the best student to the worst.

Comment: Remember that indices in Java are zero-based. In answering your question, it would be helpful to know *why* you'd want such an array.

Comment: I think you have either to change your data structure or write your own sort algorithm suited for your two array data structure.

Comment: What if a number is duplicated? Index of the first occurrence?

Comment: SInce this is a small fixed array, you could do a brute force search for the smallest, second smallest etc. or you could encode the index in the number and sort them.

Comment: you need to implement the sorting algorithm by yourself or you can just directly use the sorting methods in java api?

Comment: @kent I'm free to use what I want the only stipulation is that I should use only one method: this one (so no outside methods).

Comment: Are you sure your resulting array wasn't meant to be 0, 2, 1 instead?

Comment: @user1932739 does no outside methods also means no outside class?

Comment: @fge the resulting array seems correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of solutions using `Map`s, I'll propose an alternative using only arrays:

```
public int[] getIndices(double[] originalArray)
{
    int len = originalArray.length;

    double[] sortedCopy = originalArray.clone();
    int[] indices = new int[len];

    // Sort the copy
    Arrays.sort(sortedCopy);

    // Go through the original array: for the same index, fill the position where the
    // corresponding number is in the sorted array in the indices array
    for (int index = 0; index < len; index++)
        indices[index] = Arrays.binarySearch(sortedCopy, originalArray[index]);

    return indices;
}
```

It is, however, quite inefficient.

Comment: Again, this will not work if the original array has duplicates.

Comment: Yes, but the OP didn't specify that the array could have duplicates. Bah.

Answer (score 0):

If the student's scaore are random  you can do this (which doesn't make much sense in the real world as you cannot/do not score student to an accuracy of *exactly* 15 digits ;)

```
public static int[] sortWithIndex(double[] results) {
    class ScoreIndex implements Comparable<ScoreIndex> {
        final double score;
        final int index;

        ScoreIndex(double score, int index) {
            this.score = score;
            this.index = index;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(ScoreIndex o) {
            int cmp = Double.compare(score, o.score);
            return cmp == 0 ? Integer.compare(index, o.index) : cmp;
        }
    }
    List<ScoreIndex> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) list.add(new ScoreIndex(results[i], i));
    Collections.sort(list);
    int[] indexes = new int[results.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) indexes[i] = list.get(i).index;
    return indexes;
}
```

---

If you grade students to limit precision, say only < 6 digits you can do

```
public static void sortWithIndex(double[] results) {
    for(int i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
        results[i] = results[i] * results.length * 1e6 + i;
    Arrays.sort(results);
}
```

The `results` now contain all the original values and the index they came from in order of values, with the lower indexes first if there are duplicates.

Comment: Are you sure? And are you sure this answers the question?

Comment: @Peter: I wouldn't do that in the general case because by using such an aggressive scaling there is an important risk of overflow. But in this case this is of course acceptable.

Comment: I think that should work fine for integers but not for doubles! (and will not compile)

Comment: There is a risk that the number of digits of precision is not given.  There is no chance of overflow as the maximum is 20 and an array cannot have enough values to cause an overflow which is about 10^308.  I have no idea why it wouldn't compile for doubles. ;)

Comment: will not compile: `results` is not defined (missing 's' in declaration). Problem with double: how to recover the indexes, since question is about creating an array with the indexes?

Comment: You can obtain the indexes by using `% results.length`

Comment: module would work with `int` but not with `double` - try sorting `{  1.00, 0.75, 0.50, 0.25 }`

Comment: If you know the precision you need to multiply by a larger number. e.g. 4x or 100x in this case.

Comment: could be a problem with "random doubles"

Comment: Yap in this case random doubles are used.

Comment: @user1932739 While that is completely unrealistic, you can still do it. I have updated my anyswer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like :

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    static Integer[] getIndicesInOrder(Integer[] array)
    {
        Integer[] c = array.clone();
        Arrays.sort(c, Collections.reverseOrder());

        List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(array);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
        {
            c[i] = l.indexOf(c[i]);
        }

        return c;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Integer[] array = {2,6,3};

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getIndicesInOrder(array)));
    }
}
```

Comment: If there are duplicates in the array this fails.

Comment: @Serious can you solve it without using List. I'm too noob for that. And it's solvable without it because I've never learn List in the class of this exam.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

- Put all of the elements of `array` in a `Map<Integer, Double>` that maps the index to the value.
- Put all of the elements of the `entrySet()` of this map into a list and sort that list by values.
- Form an array out of the keys of the newly sorted list of entries.

---

```
public static int[] getIndicesInOrder(double[] array) {
    Map<Integer, Double> map = new HashMap<Integer, Double>(array.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        map.put(i, array[i]);

    List<Entry<Integer, Double>> l = 
                           new ArrayList<Entry<Integer, Double>>(map.entrySet());

    Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<Entry<?, Double>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Entry<?, Double> e1, Entry<?, Double> e2) {
                return e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue());
            }
        });

    int[] result = new int[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
        result[i] = l.get(i).getKey();

    return result;
}
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] array = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 3.3 };

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getIndicesInOrder(array)));
}
```

```
[3, 2, 4, 1, 0]
```

Comment: @Kent Indeed :-) Almost identical

Comment: yours has generic Entry, nicer than mine

Comment: @Kent No this will be descending also (I edited to include the same test as yours).

Comment: yep, e2.compareTo(e1)... didn't notice it.

Answer (score 0):

> It's an exam question. The doubles are GPAs from students and it asks
>   for a method that returns an array composed of the IDs (which in my
>   code are the indexes of double[]array) of the students from the best
>   student to the worst.

I would do it with Map. `<ID, Doubles>`. We cannot directly use TreeMap, because it is sorted by Key. We want to sort by Value(those Doubles). We could do some trick on that however, to make our own comparator impl. to sort the map by values.

I wrote it in a junit test class,

```
@Test
public void testArray() {
    final double[] array = new double[] { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 3.3 };
    final int[] result = new int[array.length];

    final Map<Integer, Double> map = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        map.put(i, array[i]);
    }
    final List<Map.Entry> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry>(map.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final Object o1, final Object o2) {
            return 0 - ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) o1).getValue()).compareTo(((Map.Entry) o2).getValue());
        }
    });
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

        result[i] = (Integer) list.get(i).getKey();
    } 

    //here we have result, to test it:
    for (final int element : result) {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
}
```

it prints:

```
    3
    2
    4
    1
    0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) comparing the values in the grades array at the respective indices,

```
import java.util.*;

public class GradeComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
    private double[] grades;
    public GradeComparator(double[] arr) {
        grades = arr;
    }
    public int compare(Integer i, Integer j) {
        return Double.compare(grades[j], grades[i]);
    }
}
```

and sort the index array using that `Comaprator`:

import java.util.*;

```
public class SortGrades {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] grades = { 2.4, 6.1, 3.9, 4.8, 5.5 };
        Integer[] ranks = new Integer[grades.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < ranks.length; ++i) {
            ranks[i] = i;
        }
        Comparator<Integer> gc = new GradeComparator(grades);
        Arrays.sort(ranks, gc);
        for(int i = 0; i < ranks.length; ++i) {
            System.out.println((i+1) + ": " + ranks[i] + ", grade: " + grades[ranks[i]]);
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
1: 1, grade: 6.1
2: 4, grade: 5.5
3: 3, grade: 4.8
4: 2, grade: 3.9
5: 0, grade: 2.4
```

as desired.

Comment: OK, not that it really matters, but why not use `Double.compare()`? Not that it matters either, but it handles NaN (though I doubt there will ever be NaNs in the array).

Comment: Simple. I didn't think of that ;)